# Is there a way to turn off wi-fi in Playwright tests without losing the ability to do requests to localhost?

Tags: automated-tests, wifi, playwright

Turn off wi-fi in test using playwright not letting me do requests to localhost.

I want to do a test using playwright, where I turn off my wi-fi connection.
However when I do this:
`await context.setOffline(true);`
I can't do requests to localhost.
And I still need to do it. Is there any workaround or other solution beside .setOffline ?

Thank is advance!

Comment: I believe you're misunderstanding what `setOffline` does. Since localhost is your backend server during development, the point of "going offline" is to simulate being unable to reach it. In production, an offline app wouldn't be able to reach anything on the internet, including your server.

Comment: you can use Playwright's route interception feature to handle the requests to localhost. checkout this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76331415/mocking-data-with-nock-in-playwright-test/76353216#76353216 or this https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/intercepting-http-requests-with-playwright#default-behavior-real-http-requests